# CodeIgniter application deployed on google cloud platform having issue for mysql database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed my codeigniter application on Google Cloud Platform. But its showing database connection error for my instance.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out
>   Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>   Line Number: 201
>
> Backtrace:
>   File: /srv/application/core/MY_Controller.php Line: 6
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: /srv/application/controllers/Home.php Line: 8
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: /srv/index.php Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

Its working fine on local, but giving issue after deploy for database connection.

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/MY_Controller.php Line Number: 6

Please provide me suggestion for above issue.

Comment: Did you change the config to match the new Location/Userid/Password of the database

Comment: Is your database on your local dev. environment? If so, app on the GCP server won't be able to access it.

Comment: Check config/database.php file might be you config wrong hostname or any other information.